# hunchentoot session- v. thread-localized values (ccl)

Tags: webserver, lisp

I'm using hunchentoot session values to make my server code re-entrant. Problem is that session values are, by definition, retained during the session, i.e., from one call from the same browser to the next, whereas what I really am looking for is what amount to thread-specific re-entrancy, so that all the values disappear between calls --  I want to treat each click as a separate "from scratch" event, even if they are from the same session . Easy enough to have the driver either set to nil, or delete my session values, but I'm wondering if there's a "correct" way to do this? I don't see any thread-based analog to hunchentoot:session-value in the documentation.

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can offer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to review the [question guidlines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a value to be "thread specific" and at the same time to be "from scratch" on every request, that requires that every request must be dispatched in a brand new thread. This is not the case according to the Hunchentoot documentation, which says that two models are supported: a single-threaded taskmaster and a thread-per-connection taskmaster.

If your configuration is multi-threaded, then a thread-specific variable bound in a request-handling can therefore be expected to be per-connection. In a single-threaded Hunchentoot setup, it will effectively be global, tied to the request servicing thread.

A thread-based analog to `hunchentoot:session-value` probably doesn't exist because it would only introduce behaviors into the web app which surprisingly change if the threading model is reconfigured, or if the request pattern from the browser changes. A browser can make multiple requests using the same connection, or close the connection between requests.

To extend the `request` objects with custom per-request, I would look into, perhaps, subclassing from the `acceptor` (how to do this is described in the docs). My custom `acceptor` would have a custom method of the `process-connection` generic function which would create extended/subclasses `request` objects carrying the extra stuff I wanted to put into a `request`.

Another way would be to have some global weak hash which binds `request` objects as keys to additional information.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. Actually the hash solution is where I ended up, but it seemed like a kludge ... which I guess it is. Since all the calls into this are eventually going to come from a client via explicit REST calls, I'm not worried about uncontrolled requests. I just wanted to wash my hand before work, and the hash solution does this just fine. Thanks!